# Mysql select the latest record between current day or next day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset of daily In and Out times of employees as follows:

```
uuid    datetime            Status  
7   2019-08-07 07:15:56     Checkout
7   2019-08-06 19:06:00     Checkin
7   2019-08-06 19:05:49     Checkout
7   2019-08-06 08:49:57     Checkin
7   2019-08-06 08:49:46     Checkout
7   2019-08-05 19:00:52     Checkin
7   2019-08-04 17:10:13     Checkout
7   2019-08-04 08:50:04     Checkin
7   2019-08-04 08:49:47     Checkout
7   2019-08-03 18:10:23     Checkin
7   2019-08-03 18:10:13     Checkout
7   2019-08-03 08:41:44     Checkin
7   2019-08-03 08:41:31     Checkout
7   2019-08-02 19:04:55     Checkin
7   2019-08-02 19:04:43     Checkout
7   2019-08-02 08:54:06     Checkin
7   2019-08-02 08:53:49     Checkout
7   2019-08-01 18:55:05     Checkin
7   2019-08-01 07:16:47     Checkout
7   2019-07-31 18:28:11     Checkin
7   2019-07-31 07:15:24     Checkout
7   2019-07-30 19:05:45     Checkin
7   2019-07-30 19:05:33     Checkout
7   2019-07-30 08:56:11     Checkin
7   2019-07-30 08:56:00     Checkout
```

Using this data I wanted to calculate the total number of hours worked during the day. The default shifts as 07.00 till 16:00 and 16:00 till 01:00 next day. From 01:00 till 06:00 OT time.

My challenge was when an employee Checkins at 07:00 and works till next day morning till 03:00 (both the shifts + few OT hours)  I used the following SQL to retrieve the Checkout time but it only return results if checking happens on the same day. I'm unable to retrieve results if Checkout time was 03:00, 3:30, 4:00, etc...

Also there cam be more that one chekins & checkouts that can take place but have to consider the earliest checkin and the latest checkout

In the following QUERY I'm trying to retrieve the Checkout time, it only return results if checkout time exists for the same day not if it happens after midnight.

```
SELECT uuid, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%M %d %Y") AS outdate, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%H:%i") AS outtimes FROM attendance_logs WHERE status = 'Checkout' AND (DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d 13:00:00") AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d 09:30:00")) AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") < "2019-08-08" ORDER BY datetime DESC
```

Expected Output (Edited to fix the result on 2019-08-05)

---

```
uuid    date      Checkin   Checkout
7         2019-08-06  08:49:57   07:15:56
7         2019-08-05  19:00:52   08:49:46
7         2019-08-04  08:50:04    17:10:13
7         2019-08-03  08:41:44    08:49:47
7         2019-08-02  08:54:06    08:41:31
7         2019-08-01  18:55:05    08:53:49
7         2019-07-31  07:16:47    18:28:11
7         2019-07-30  08:56:11    07:15:24
```

Final SQL query

```
 select attendance_logs.uuid
      , emp.name
      , dept.name AS department_name
      , DATE_FORMAT(attendance_logs.datetime
      , "%M %d %Y") AS day
      , cintimes.intimes AS cin 
      , couttimes.outtimes AS cout  
   from attendance_logs 
   left 
   join employees AS emp 
     on emp.uuid = attendance_logs.uuid 
    and emp.is_disabled = 0 
    and emp.is_valid = 1 
   left 
   join departments AS dept 
     on dept.id = attendance_logs.department_id 
    and dept.is_disabled = 0 
    and dept.is_valid = 1 
   left 
   join 
      ( SELECT uuid
             , DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%M %d %Y") AS indate
             , DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%H:%i") AS intimes 
          FROM  attendance_logs 
         WHERE status = 'Checkin' 
           AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") <= "2019-08-07" 
         GROUP 
            BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%M %d %Y")
             , uuid 
         ORDER 
            BY datetime DESC ) AS cintimes 
     on cintimes.uuid = attendance_logs.uuid 
    and cintimes.indate = DATE_FORMAT(attendance_logs.datetime, "%M %d %Y") 
   left 
   join 
      ( SELECT uuid
             , DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%M %d %Y") AS outdate
             , DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%H:%i") AS outtimes 
          FROM attendance_logs 
         WHERE status = 'Checkout' 
           AND (DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s") BETWEEN  DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d 13:00:00") AND  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d 09:30:00")) 
           AND DATE_FORMAT(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d") < "2019-08-07" 
         ORDER 
            BY datetime DESC ) AS couttimes 
     on couttimes.uuid = attendance_logs.uuid 
    and couttimes.outdate = DATE_FORMAT(attendance_logs.datetime, "%M %d %Y") 
  where attendance_logs.uuid = ? 
  group 
     by DATE_FORMAT(attendance_logs.datetime, "%M %d %Y")
      , attendance_logs.uuid 
  order 
     by attendance_logs.datetime desc
```

Comment: It seems like someone is working from 19:06 on August 6 to 7:15 on August 7. Is that allowed?

Comment: @Strawberry Updated the post to show the expected output - Just above the Final query section

Comment: @Nick These are from the clerical staff who works on shift basis (Printing Press)

Comment: @Strawberry, my bad. I have corrected the final results

Comment: Where does '2019-07-31  07:16:47' come from, and why is it in the checkin column? This is really confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data set:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+------+---------------------+----------+
| uuid | datetime            | Status   |
+------+---------------------+----------+
|    7 | 2019-07-30 08:56:00 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-07-30 08:56:11 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-07-30 19:05:33 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-07-30 19:05:45 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-07-31 07:15:24 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-07-31 18:28:11 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-01 07:16:47 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-01 18:55:05 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 08:53:49 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 08:54:06 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 19:04:43 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 19:04:55 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 08:41:31 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 08:41:44 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 18:10:13 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 18:10:23 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-04 08:49:47 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-04 08:50:04 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-04 17:10:13 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-05 19:00:52 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 08:49:46 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 08:49:57 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 19:05:49 | Checkout |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 19:06:00 | Checkin  |
|    7 | 2019-08-07 07:15:56 | Checkout |
+------+---------------------+----------+
```

Here's a partial result...

```
 SELECT x.uuid
      , x.datetime checkin
      , MIN(y.datetime) checkout
   FROM my_table x 
   LEFT 
   JOIN my_table y 
     ON y.datetime > x.datetime 
    AND y.status = 'checkout' 
  WHERE x.status = 'checkin' 
  GROUP 
     BY x.datetime;

+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| uuid | checkin             | checkout            |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    7 | 2019-07-30 08:56:11 | 2019-07-30 19:05:33 |
|    7 | 2019-07-30 19:05:45 | 2019-07-31 07:15:24 |

|    7 | 2019-07-31 18:28:11 | 2019-08-01 07:16:47 |

|    7 | 2019-08-01 18:55:05 | 2019-08-02 08:53:49 |

|    7 | 2019-08-02 08:54:06 | 2019-08-02 19:04:43 |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 19:04:55 | 2019-08-03 08:41:31 |

|    7 | 2019-08-03 08:41:44 | 2019-08-03 18:10:13 |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 18:10:23 | 2019-08-04 08:49:47 |

|    7 | 2019-08-04 08:50:04 | 2019-08-04 17:10:13 |

|    7 | 2019-08-05 19:00:52 | 2019-08-06 08:49:46 |

|    7 | 2019-08-06 08:49:57 | 2019-08-06 19:05:49 |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 19:06:00 | 2019-08-07 07:15:56 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I still can't follow the logic that gets us from here to your desired result.

EDIT:

Here's something that looks very like your desired result, but I don't know if it's really what you're after...

```
SELECT uuid
     , MIN(checkin) checkin
     , MAX(checkout) checkout
  FROM
     (  SELECT x.uuid
             , x.datetime checkin
             , MIN(y.datetime) checkout
             , DATE(x.datetime-INTERVAL 8 HOUR) dt
          FROM my_table x
          LEFT
          JOIN my_table y
            ON y.uuid = x.uuid
           AND y.datetime > x.datetime
           AND y.status = 'checkout'
         WHERE x.status = 'checkin'
         GROUP
            BY x.datetime
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY uuid
     , dt;
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| uuid | checkin             | checkout            |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
|    7 | 2019-07-30 08:56:11 | 2019-07-31 07:15:24 |
|    7 | 2019-07-31 18:28:11 | 2019-08-01 07:16:47 |
|    7 | 2019-08-01 18:55:05 | 2019-08-02 08:53:49 |
|    7 | 2019-08-02 08:54:06 | 2019-08-03 08:41:31 |
|    7 | 2019-08-03 08:41:44 | 2019-08-04 08:49:47 |
|    7 | 2019-08-04 08:50:04 | 2019-08-04 17:10:13 |
|    7 | 2019-08-05 19:00:52 | 2019-08-06 08:49:46 |
|    7 | 2019-08-06 08:49:57 | 2019-08-07 07:15:56 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: This SQL works well. Found a small glitch in a situation when there isn't any checkout record corresponds to a day. Thank you

Comment: I don't get how that's a 'glitch', but ok.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to format it a little bit, but I think that's what you want:

```sql
select
   al.uuid,
   al.datetime as checkin,
   (
      select min(datetime) 
      from attendance_logs 
      where status = 'CheckOut' and datetime > al.datetime 
   ) as checkout 
from attendance_logs al 
where al.status = 'CheckIn';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply. I needed to select the most previous time as the Checkin time while the latest time (most nearest to 7:00 am next day ) as the Checkout time.  This query tend to output more that one result for a selected day. Hope you could further assist me on this part also.